# Why this javascript code work? why wrapper function can receive object from 'click' event while it just has one parameter

Tags: javascript

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

const wrapper = fn => {
  return (obj) => {
    fn(obj)
  }
}

const clickHandler = (obj) => {
  console.log(obj)
}

button.addEventListener('click', wrapper(clickHandler)) //why wrapper can receive object from 'click' event ?**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button>button</button>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Why this javascript code work? why wrapper function can receive object from 'click' event while it just has one parameter**

Comment: It's working in your snippet here in the page. The event object gets logged to the console. Are you expecting something different?

Comment: yes, its working, my question is, why its working? especially on the wrapper function for event handler

Comment: Wrapper returns a function and that is the function that gets called when event occurs. First argument of an event handler is the event object ... or `obj` in the wrapper internal function. Then `fn(obj)` gets called which is the same as `clickHandler(obj)`

Comment: wow thank you for your help, its clear now

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it right away.